# Cannot Connect Modem ( /dev/ttySL0 ) Using gnome-ppp - Dial-Up Connection

Tags: 10.04, hardware, modem

I'm trying to connect my Toshiba Satellite running Ubuntu 10.04 to my Eris running Android 2.1 through a Bluetooth connection and establish a dial-up connection (DUN) with the modem.  I can connect my phone to my laptop, and I can detect my modem (after installing drivers), which is located at `/dev/ttySL0`.  But when I launch `gnome-ppp` and enter my phone number ([123 for PDA-Net](http://www.junefabrics.com/android/bluetooth.php)) I get a dialog that says "Connecting...  Sending Password" with Log and Cancel buttons.  The log shows this:

`--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.60`
`--> Cannot get information for serial port.`
`--> Initializing modem.`
`--> Sending: ATZ`
`ATZ`
`OK`
`--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0`
`ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0`
`OK`
`--> Modem initialized.`
`--> Please enter password (or empty password to stop):`
`--> Configuration does not specify a valid login name.`

The PDA-Net DUN protocol is running and shows no error.  Any ideas?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

From the [PDA-Net](http://www.junefabrics.com/android/bluetooth.php) website:

> Since this is just a regular Bluetooth
>   DUN connection, you have 3 ways to
>   initiate the dialup:
>
> 1. You can use the Bluetooth software to connect if available. For some
>      drivers such as the BlueSoleil one,
>      this is the only way you can initiate
>      the connection.
> 2. You can open network connections panel and launch the Bluetooth entry.
>
> For 1 and 2, enter phone number #777
>   and empty username/password when
>   prompted.

Comment: This resource describes the setup for Windows, and may or may not work for Linux.  Setting this up on Windows is simple.  I have done this on several machines.  Linux, however, is more difficult, because the drivers are tricky to install...  I can connect to my laptop with my phone, using Bluetooth.  This is not the problem.  It's the connection.  But...  I will look into BlueSoleil anyway, as it may have some benefit.

Comment: I posted the quote for this snippet "enter phone number #777 and empty username/password when prompted."